# JQueryMobile button group configuration

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

JQueryMobile offers the capability to [group buttons](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html) either horizontally:

```
BtnA | BtnB
```

or vertically:

```
BtnA
----
BtnB
```

via the `controlgroup` configuration.

Is the following set up, involving both horizontal and vertical placement, possible:

```
BtnA | BtnB
-----------
BtnC | BtnD
```

If yes, how? Any alternatives to `controlgroup` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using JQM content grid Like this:

```
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="button" data-theme="c">Previous</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="button" data-theme="c">Next</button></div>      
            <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="button" data-theme="c">Previous</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="button" data-theme="c">Next</button></div>     
        </div>
```

Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/kkf9w/

Heres the JQM docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: Nice, +1ed; will wait for other answers though.